# I can't transfer files using pscp to amazon AWS ec2 instances. Key refused

Tags: amazon-ec2, putty, private-key, pscp

I can connect to the server command line using Putty using the same private key.

But when I try to use the same key to transfer a file from my PC over to the server":

**pscp -i C:\xxx.ppk  "C:\xx\somefile.yy" ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/(some location)**

I receive the following error:

**Server refused our key
Fatal: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent:
 publickey)**

Could someone help me with fixing this problem please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to review the [Error: Server refused our key or No supported authentication methods available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingPuTTY) section of the [Troubleshooting Connecting to Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingPuTTY) document.

Try this: add the -l user name option to the pscp command line, with the proper username for your instance.

> pscp -i C:\xxx.ppk -l user ec2-user "C:\xx\somefile.yy" ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/(some location)

The -l option allows you to connect with specified username. You may have a username mismatch.

Answer (score 4):

btw guys none of the examples above didn't work for me and here is what I use:

1. With putty I converted .pem file into .ppk: Conversions->importkey->save private key (now we have .ppk)
2. `pscp -scp -i c:/ssh-key/ssh.ppk ./dist/* ubuntu@ec2-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/www`

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I was using a destination syntax of username@ipaddr:/dir and got this error.
I had to use username@hostname:/dir.  Surprised I had to specify the hostname...